On-demand InvokeModel requests per minute for Amazon Titan Text Express
The maximum number of times that you can call InvokeModel and InvokeModelWithResponseStream in one minute. The quota considers the combined sum of InvokeModel and InvokeModelWithResponseStream requests for Amazon Titan Text Express.
This quote is set to zero in my aws account. We need a positive quota to even to try this model in playground. It is not even adjustable by requesting unlike other quotas.
There's no requesting option to increase. Now if I try to use the model it throws this following error

ThrottlingException: An error occurred (ThrottlingException) when calling the InvokeModel operation (reached max retries: 4): Too many requests, please wait before trying again. You have sent too many requests.  Wait before trying again.

How to work with this model now?



The docs says, "The On-demand model invocation quotas in Amazon Bedrock endpoints and quotas in the AWS General Reference aren't adjustable through Service Quotas. Contact your AWS account manager to be considered for an increase.
Note
Due to overwhelming demand, priority will be given to customers who generate traffic that consumes their existing quota allocation. Your request might be denied if you don't meet this condition."

Thanks. I've raised a ticket for that. Not resolved yet. I'll update after ticket is processed

It is resolved after raising that ticket but aws support takes long time (12 days appx.) to resolve.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
